# woocommerce product attributes dropdown not appear

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i can't select product color or size before add product to cart .
all attributes showing like text not selection
i need to show product attributes dropdown list (options)

i try :

```
// Remove additional information tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_additional_information_tab', 100, 1 );
function remove_additional_information_tab( $tabs ) {
    unset($tabs['additional_information']);

    return $tabs;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN2gw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Once you’ve created attributes you’ll need to use those to create variations on your product. I assume what you’re saying is that you click on an attribute and it then takes you to a page showing you any product that is using that attribute.
once your attributes are added to the product follow the rest of this [doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) to get variations created. Then you’ll have drop down options for those variations on your product.